# Statement for checking only once?Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell

I have two lists of unequal length. When I add both of them I want the final list to have the length of the longest list.

```
addtwolists [0,0,221,2121] [0,0,0,99,323,99,32,2332,23,23]
>[0,0,221,2220,323,99,32,2332,23,23]
addtwolists [945,45,4,45,22,34,2] [0,34,2,34,2]
>[945,79,6,79,24,34,2]

zerolist :: Int -> [Integer]
zerolist x = take x (repeat 0)

addtwolists :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
addtwolists x y = zipWith (+) (x ++ (zerolist ((length y)-(length x)))) (y ++ (zerolist ((length x)-(length y))))
```

This code is inefficient. So I tried:

```
addtwolist :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
addtwolist x y = zipWith (+) (x ++ [head (zerolist ((length y)-(length x))) | (length y) > (length x)]) (y ++ [head (zerolist ((length x)-(length y))) | (length x) > (length y)])
```

Any other way to increase the efficiency?Could you only check once to see which list is bigger?

Comment: In addition to all answers: You could use `Int`, unless you need arbitrary large `Integer`s, but be aware that `Int` is `Int32`/`Int64` on 32/64-bit operating systems.

Comment: and if you really need `length x` in some cases, extract it in a `where lx = length x` statement, so you can use it multiple times without evaluating/calculating it every time it occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because I can't help bikeshedding, you might enjoy this function:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid Data.List> :t map mconcat . transpose
map mconcat . transpose :: Monoid b => [[b]] -> [b]
```

For example:

```
> map (getSum . mconcat) . transpose $ [map Sum [0..5], map Sum [10,20..100]]
[10,21,32,43,54,65,70,80,90,100]
```

Answer (score 7):

Your implementation is slow because it looks like you call the length function on each list multiple times on each step of zipWith. Haskell computes list length by walking the entire list and counting the number of elements it traverses.

The first speedy method that came to my mind was explicit recursion.

```
addLists :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
addLists xs     []     = xs
addLists []     ys     = ys
addLists (x:xs) (y:ys) = x + y : addLists xs ys
```

I'm not aware of any standard Prelude functions that would fill your exact need, but if you wanted to generalize this to a higher order function, you could do worse than this. The two new values passed to the zip function are filler used in computing the remaining portion of the long list after the short list has been exhausted.

```
zipWithExtend :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> a -> b -> [c]
zipWithExtend f []     []     a' b' = []
zipWithExtend f (a:as) []     a' b' = f a  b' : zipWithExtend f as [] a' b'
zipWithExtend f []     (b:bs) a' b' = f a' b  : zipWithExtend f [] bs a' b'
zipWithExtend f (a:as) (b:bs) a' b' = f a b   : zipWithExtend f as bs a' b'
```

Usage:

```
> let as = [0,0,221,2121]
> let bs = [0,0,0,99,323,99,32,2332,23,23]
> zipWithExtend (+) as bs 0 0
[0,0,221,2220,323,99,32,2332,23,23]
```

Comment: I've often preferred `zipWithExtend :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> [c]` to the type you used.

Comment: Good idea. It took me a while to see why exactly, so for anyone who comes across this in the future, it's because my version is really a special case of @JohnL's. Consider a modified version of mine that worked in this way, `zipWithExtend f as bs (flip f b) (f a)`.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done in a single iteration, which should be a significant improvement for long lists.  It's probably simplest with explicit recursion:

```
addTwoLists xs [] = xs
addTwoLists [] ys = ys
addTwoLists (x:xs) (y:ys) = x+y:addTwoLists xs ys
```

Comment: Could you explain how `x+y:addTwoLists` works? What is the colon for?

Comment: `:` is the list constructor, it's equivalent to `cons`.  The way the third case works is by pattern matching on two input lists to get the heads and tails.  The output is created by adding the two list heads to create a new list head, then cons'ing that onto the output of `addTwoLists` to the list tails.  One neat thing about data constructors is that you can use them for pattern-matching on the LHS, and also for creating data on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

```
addtwolists xs ys = 
  let common = zipWith (+) xs ys
      len = length common
  in common ++ drop len xs ++ drop len ys   

addtwolists xs ys | length xs < length ys = zipWith (+) (xs ++ repeat 0) ys
                  | otherwise = zipWith (+) xs (ys ++ repeat 0)
```